# Extract value from list of xml elements with jaxb

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have an XML doc structured like

```
<thing>
  <attr name="one">first</attr>
  <attr name="two">second</attr>
  <attr name="three">third</attr>
</thing>
```

I have JAXB classes that are set up like so:

```
public class Thing {
    List<Attribute> attr = new ArrayList<Attribute>();
    @XmlElement(name="attr")
    public List<Attribute> getAttr() { return this.attr; }
    public void setAttr(List<Attribute> attr) { this.attr = attr; }
}

public class Attribute {
    String value;
    String name;

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getName() { return this.name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

    @XmlElement
    public String getValue() { return this.value;}
    public void setValue(String value) { this.value = value; }
}
```

When I unmarshal the document, if I loop over `for (Attribute a : thing.getAttr())` doing `a.getName()` it prints the "one", "two", "three" but the `a.getValue()` is just null.

Am I annotating it incorrectly? Even if I set the annotation to `@XmlElement(name="attr")` it appears to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will solve your problem:

```
@XmlValue
public String getValue() { return this.value;}
```

That's not a child element but the current element value you are looking for.

**EDIT:** and BTW you should add an `@XmlRootElement` annotation on Thing class in case if it's missing.

Comment: Thanks, I completely forgot that XmlValue thing even existed for some reason.